# How to select all elements who has id, appropriating to regular expression

Tags: jquery

I need to count all elements who has id like 'hi*'.

For example, if we have markup below:

```
<div id="hi1"></div>
<div id="hi2"></div>
```

Num value has to be '2'.

In the web I have found this:

```
var num = $('.insttip:regex(id,'+ id[0] + '*').length;
```

But this is not working :(
Thank you!

Comment: You may want to consider using a class called `hi` and selecting with `$('.hi');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/iyolih/edit#javascript,html,live)*

try with:

```
var num = $('div[id^=hi]').length;
```

The `^` selector means `starts with`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test regular expressions against elements' attributes without resorting to jQuery plugins, you can do this with [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). Example:

```
$('div').filter(function () {
    return /^hi.*$/.test(this.id);
});
```

Or if you want numbers only:

```
$('div').filter(function () {
    return /^hi\d+$/.test(this.id);
});
```

In this case, you can use the `[id^="hi"]` selector as documented by other answers. But this is not a general way to use regular expressions. The `.filter()` method provides more flexibility than the built-in jQuery selectors, so it's generally a good method to be familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('div[id^="hi"]').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a specific jQuery selector for this case: [Starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

You can do something like this:

```
$('div[id^="hi"]').length
```